# MATLAB reading CSV file with timestamp and values

Tags: matlab, csv, matrix, import

I have the following sample from a CSV file. Structure is:

```
Date      ,Time(Hr:Min:S:mS), Value
2015:08:20,08:20:19:123     , 0.05234
2015:08:20,08:20:19:456     , 0.06234
```

I then would like to read this into a matrix in MATLAB.

Attempt :

```
Matrix = csvread('file_name.csv');
```

Also tried an attempt formatting the string.

```
fmt = %u:%u:%u %u:%u:%u:%u %f
Matrix = csvread('file_name.csv',fmt);
```

The problem is when the file is read the format is wrong and displays it differently.

Any help or advice given would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT

When using @Adriaan answer the result is

```
2015 -11 -9
8    -17 -1
```

So it seems that MATLAB thinks the '-' is the delimiter(separator)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Matrix = csvread('file_name.csv',1,0);
```

[`csread`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/csvread.html) does not support a format specifier. Just enter the number of header rows (I took it to be one, as per example), and number of header columns, 0.

You file, however, contains non-numeric data. Thus import it with [`importdata`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/importdata.html):

```
 data = importdata('file_name.csv')
```

This will get you a structure, `data` with two fields: `data.data` contains the numeric data, i.e. a vector containing your `value`. `data.textdata` is a cell containing the rest of the data, you need the first two column and extract the numerics from it, i.e.

```
for ii = 2:size(data.textdata,1)
    tmp1 = data.textdata{ii,1};
    Date(ii,1) = datenum(tmp1,'YYYY:MM:DD');
    tmp2 = data.textdata{ii,2};
    Date(ii,2) = datenum(tmp2,'HH:MM:SS:FFF');
end
```

Thanks to @Excaza it turns out milliseconds are supported.

Comment: Please see the edit when your solution was attempted :)

Comment: @user3536870 I do not understand how you got your numbers from the provided sample data using the method provided here

Comment: I got the result by using Matrix = csvread('filename.csv',1,0); The loop wasn't in the answer when I attempted this and then it gave the result in my edit for the question. And no headers

Comment: @user3536870 the looped version seems to work OK. Note that in case your header is not included you need to run the `for` loop from 1, and not 2. Everything else can remain as put